# Android: Formatting a Calendar object contains p.m. on one device and PM on another device

Tags: android

When formatting a `Calendar` object in Android using `SimpleDateFormat` class with a pattern of `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mma`, produces `2016-02-19 06:31PM` on one device and `2016-02-19 06:33p.m.` on another device.

Is there any settings on the device that influence this behavior? or is it because of Android OS Level?

I tried on the devices running following OS

Android 6.0.1. (This produces string that contains p.m.)

Android 5.0.2. (This produces string that contains PM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SimpleDateFormate is device's default Locale Dependent, if you want a constant formatting for all devices just specify your required Locale to SimpleDateFormat object like:
SimpleDateFormat formatShort = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa", REQUIRED_LOCALE);

Comment: is it possible to change the locale setting on the device level instead of coding?

Comment: Locale represents a language/country/variant combination. If you change device language indirectly you are changing its locale. The default locale is not appropriate for machine-readable output. The best choice there is usually Locale.US – this locale is guaranteed to be available on all devices

Comment: I tested on 2 devices, please check the difference p.m and PM

          a) on Android OS 6.0.1, changing language to English (UK) produces 2016-02-19 06:31p.m., and English (US) produces 2016-02-19 06:31PM

            b) on Android OS 5.0.2, changing language to English (UK) and  English (US) produces the same 2016-02-19 06:31pm

Comment: is there any other settings influence this behavior or is it because of OS version

Comment: You can construct new locale programmatically. 
Go through this: [http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html]